# What command in MySQL is like the command "host" in oracle sqlplus

Tags: linux, command-line, mysql, database, oracle-10g

Oracle sqlplus allows you to drop down to a system command line shell which lets you run operating system command like ls, cd, cp, etc.

Here are examples [SQL*Plus_FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.21_and_HOST.3F), [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1010003)

Is there some thing that does the same in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/shell-commands-mysql-command-line-client/

From the mysql help

> mysql> ?
>   ...
>   system    (\!) Execute a system shell command.
>
> mysql> \! bash
>   mysql> system bash
>   mysql> \! ls
>   mysql> system ls